# How can I access this text widget from another function?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm trying to insert text into the textbox I've created in the **init** function through the write_line function. My aim is to be able to dynamically add text to the text box, similar to how a command console works (if there is a better widget or way to go about this, please let me know). However, I'm not sure how I can access the text widget from outside the init function. I'm using the latest version of python.

```
class Console(Text, Scrollbar):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Text.__init__(self, parent)
        Scrollbar.__init__(self, parent)

        text = Text(parent)
        scroll = Scrollbar(parent)
        text.focus_set()

        scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        scroll.config(command=text.yview)
        text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

        # text.insert(END, 'this is a test') <-- need to move this statement to the write line function

    # write line to text box
    def write_line(self):

        pass
```

Comment: is `write_line` part of the class? Your indentation is messed up.

Comment: Yes it was. I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'self.' when declaring the variable so that instead of just 'text' it becomes 'self.text'.

```
class Console(Text, Scrollbar):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Text.__init__(self, parent)
        Scrollbar.__init__(self, parent)

        self.text = Text(parent)
        scroll = Scrollbar(parent)
        self.text.focus_set()

        scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        scroll.config(command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

    # write line to text box
    def write_line(self):

        self.text.insert(END, 'this is a test') # there
```